# The reducer sorts the serial numbers automatically on ascending instead of under each other?

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, ngrx, ngrx-store

I'm playing around with NgRx.

What strikes me, is that if I add a product (part) to the Redux store via the reducer. Source code of orders.reducer.ts:

```
case OrderActions.ADD_ORDER: {
  const partOrder =  action.payload;

  const entities = {
    ...state.entities,
    [partOrder.part.serialNo]: {...partOrder}
  };

  return {
    ...state,
    entities
  };
}
```

The reducer sorts the serial numbers automatically on ascending instead of under each other?

See:
[image: printscreen of state]

How can I add the serialnumber under each other in the 'entities' array?

Please help me out!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The type of entities is an object in your redux state. If you want to keep the original order you should change the type of the entities to array.

```
case OrderActions.ADD_ORDER: {
  const partOrder =  action.payload;

  const entities = [ // it is array now
    ...state.entities,
    {...partOrder}
  ];

  return {
    ...state,
    entities
  };
}
```

But you could not access the orders by serial number now. You shold use a selector if you want to keep that functionality.

Comment: So if the type is an Object, then javascript automatically sorts on alphabetically ascending?

Comment: With object there is no order for the properties. The redux viewer use the  alpabetic order for displaying. If you iterate trough the object keys you might get another order.

Comment: Hi Peter, can I disable the alphabetic order in the redux viewer? And how can I iterate through the object key?

Comment: What do you expect disabling the alphabetical order? Object do not keep order. If it is not alphabetical, then you can get random. And yes you can iterate trought the object keys. Search for Object.keys.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I have refactored the sourcecode, now it's an array instead of an Object. And I get the data via de index number